# Is there a way I can find the range of local maxima of histogram?

Tags: python, scipy, histogram

I'm wondering if there's a way I can find the range of local maxima of a histogram. For instance, suppose I have the following histogram (just ignore the orange curve):[image]
The histogram is actually obtained from a dictionary. I'm hoping to find the range of local maxima of this histogram (on the horizontal axis), which are, say, 1.3-1.6, and 2.1-2.4 in this case. I have no idea which tools would be helpful or which techniques I may want to use. I know there's a tool to find local maxima of a 1-D array:

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
x = np.random.random(12)
argrelextrema(x, np.greater)
```

but I don't think it would work here since I'm looking for a range, and there're some 'wiggles' on the histogram. Can anyone give me some suggestions/examples about how I can obtain the range I'm looking for? Thanks a lot for the help

PS: I trying to not just search for the ranges of x whose y values are above a certain limit:)

Comment: I do not know scipy, but in general, local maxima is where a change of the value of your function is changing sign. You can convolute your function with some averaging function to remove "noise".

Comment: @user3431635 Thanks for the comment! But here I want to keep the data of my original histogram.

Comment: do you have discrete values or continuous?

Comment: @Aven Desta The values of the histogram are discrete:)

Comment: how would you define "range" - by what standard?

Comment: @Koko Jumbo Thank you for the comment:) I want to define the range like finding the highest peak (in the local maximum), then 'extend' on both sides by a certain value, say if my highest bin corresponds to 1.45, then if I extend 0.15 on both sides, then the range would be 1.3-1.6. Maybe there's a better way to define that:)

Comment: I have not tested this but scipy also have the method `find_peaks`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html. you might find your answer there

Comment: @Koko Jumbo Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question but here is how I might try to solve your problem:
- Since you have discrete points, I would use Lagrange's interpolation to make a polynomial representing the graph
- Then I would use the usual calculus (derivative) theorems to find local minima and maxima

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if I correctly understand what you want to do, but you can treat the histogram as a Probability Density Function (PDF) of a bimodal distribution, then find the modes and the Highest Density Intervals (HDIs) around the two modes.

So, I create some sample data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as sps
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, argrelextrema
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d1 = sps.norm(loc=1.3, scale=.2)
d2 = sps.norm(loc=2.2, scale=.3)

r1 = d1.rvs(size=5000, random_state=1)
r2 = d2.rvs(size=5000, random_state=1)

r = np.concatenate((r1, r2))

h = plt.hist(r, bins=100, density=True);
```

[image]

We have only `h`, the result of the `hist` function that will contains the density (100) and the ranges of the bins (101).

```
print(h[0].size)
100
print(h[1].size)
101
```

So we first need to choose the mean of each bin

```
density = h[0]
values = h[1][:-1] + np.diff(h[1])[0] / 2

plt.hist(r, bins=100, density=True, alpha=.25)
plt.plot(values, density);
```

[image]

Now we can normalize the PDF (to sum to 1) and smooth the data with moving average that we'll use only to get the peaks (maxima) and minima

```
norm_density = density / density.sum()
norm_density_ma = pd.Series(norm_density).rolling(7, center=True).mean().values

plt.plot(values, norm_density_ma)
plt.plot(values, norm_density);
```

[image]

Now we can obtain indexes of maxima

```
peaks = find_peaks(norm_density_ma)[0]
peaks
array([24, 57])
```

and minima

```
minima = argrelextrema(norm_density_ma, np.less)[0]
minima
array([40])
```

and check they're correct

```
plt.plot(values, norm_density_ma)
plt.plot(values, norm_density)
for peak in peaks:
    plt.axvline(values[peak], color='r')
plt.axvline(values[minima], color='k', ls='--');
```

[image]

Finally, we have to find out the HDIs around the two modes (peaks) from the normalized `h` histogram data. We can use a simple function to get the HDI of grid (see [HDI_of_grid](https://github.com/aloctavodia/Doing_bayesian_data_analysis/blob/master/HDI_of_grid.py) for details and [Doing Bayesian Data Analysis by John K. Kruschke](http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com))

```
def HDI_of_grid(probMassVec, credMass=0.95):
    sortedProbMass = np.sort(probMassVec, axis=None)[::-1]
    HDIheightIdx = np.min(np.where(np.cumsum(sortedProbMass) >= credMass))
    HDIheight = sortedProbMass[HDIheightIdx]
    HDImass = np.sum(probMassVec[probMassVec >= HDIheight])
    idx = np.where(probMassVec >= HDIheight)[0]
    return {'indexes':idx, 'mass':HDImass, 'height':HDIheight}
```

Let's say we want the HDIs to contain a mass of 0.3

```
# HDI around the 1st mode
hdi1 = HDI_of_grid(norm_density, credMass=.3)

plt.plot(values, norm_density_ma)
plt.plot(values, norm_density)
plt.fill_between(
    values[hdi1['indexes']], 
    0, norm_density[hdi1['indexes']],
    alpha=.25
)
for peak in peaks:
    plt.axvline(values[peak], color='r')
```

[image]

for the 2nd mode, we'll get HDI from `minima` to avoid the 1st mode

```
# HDI around the 2nd mode
hdi2 = HDI_of_grid(norm_density[minima[0]:], credMass=.3)

plt.plot(values, norm_density_ma)
plt.plot(values, norm_density)
plt.fill_between(
    values[hdi1['indexes']], 
    0, norm_density[hdi1['indexes']],
    alpha=.25
)
plt.fill_between(
    values[hdi2['indexes']+minima], 
    0, norm_density[hdi2['indexes']+minima],
    alpha=.25
)
for peak in peaks:
    plt.axvline(values[peak], color='r')
```

[image]

And we have the values of the two HDIs

```
# 1st mode
values[peaks[0]]
1.320249129265321
# 0.3 HDI
values[hdi1['indexes']].take([0, -1])
array([1.12857599, 1.45715851])

# 2nd mode
values[peaks[1]]
2.2238510564735363
# 0.3 HDI
values[hdi2['indexes']+minima].take([0, -1])
array([1.95003229, 2.47028795])
```